# remove smarty -> assign variable from controller in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I modified the default prestashop 1.5 newsletter module and made the following override of to the IdentityController

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('newsletter', (int)Module::getInstanceByName('modifiednewsletter')->active);
```

So the checkbox would appear to set/unset newsletter subscription via the "my personal information" account link.

Everything works fine but with `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` i still get the following php error on the personal info page

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/prestashop/controllers/front/IdentityController.php on line 135 Call Stack: 0.0001 646712 1.
```

line 135 of IdentityController.php is

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('newsletter', (int)Module::getInstanceByName('blocknewsletter')->active);
```

When i comment out the line, the error goes away, but I really don't want to mess with the core files, can anyone tell me how to "unset" this variable through the override file?

Comment: Can you show us where you've added this code exactly? In what method you use it and what else do you do? Do you call the parent's method?

Comment: `public function initContent()
 {
  parent::initContent();

  $this->context->smarty->assign('newsletter', (int)Module::getInstanceByName('berlindisplaynewsletter')->active);

 }`  I do call the parent's method since half the page doesn't work if i don't maybe i should should use a new function in the override and not `initContent()` ? I'm pretty new to php and prestashop so i just kinda hack my way through all this without really knowing what i do ...

Answer (score 0):

Create file **IdentityController.php** in **override/controllers/front/**.

Now copy the method you are having problem with into this file and comment line with faulty code.

**You also want to delete file tools/smarty/index.php to force smarty template recompilation!** (Rookie mistake)

For your information, this notice is thrown because you are trying to access variable named "active" of object that does not exist.

This is accessing public attribute:

```
$instance = new Module;
$instance->active;
```

This is calling public static method of class Module:

```
Module::getInstanceByName('blocknewsletter');
```

In this call no object is really created because non is needed.

Thankfully passing non-existing variable into smarty template isn't fatal error and application can keep running ignoring this mistake.